# PHP for Mysql DB Connection - How safe is it?

Tags: php, mysql

As part of my rookie knowledge, I learned from some videos on youtube how to create database connections with Php. The php file looks like this:

```
<?php 

DEFINE ('someuser', 'someuser'); 
DEFINE ('somepass', 'somepass'); 
DEFINE ('somehost', 'somehost'); 
DEFINE ('somedbname', 'somedbname'); 

$dbc = mysqli_connect(somehost,someuser,somepass);
if (!$dbc) {
    die("Database connection failed: " . mysqli_error($dbc));
    exit();
}
```

Now, basically I am writing my username and password here in a file. Is this a safe way to do this, or is there a safer method to make things, well, safer.

Comment: safe for what? safety isn't a simple on/off toggle. You need to explain what your threat vectors are.

Comment: In terms of being able to download this data, it's safe enough. Make sure your MySQL server is not accessible to the general internet though.

Comment: well, you've gotta put the password somewhere, whether it be in that file or in another.

Comment: safe: will I be hacked easily?

Answer (score 0):

This is the usually followed method. There shouldn't be any security issues. If someone has read access to the above files, then they will be able to see the password. But if an unauthorized person has read access to your php files, then you have much larger problems to be worried about.

Comment: will anyone have read access to files in the www folder of my website?

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a littlebit safer. Let's says, this file is the `conn.php`.

If this is your directory structure:

```
/home/me/
/home/me/www/
```

Your document root is `/home/me/www/`.

Put the `conn.php` outside of the `www` directory, into `/home/me/conn.php`. So nobody can access it from outside, but you can acces it from your `www` directory.

Comment: actually I'm using mobile apps to use that file to download data. will I be able to call the file from the app with this method?

Comment: It's not related to the client side. What I've mentioned, is happens on server side.